# How to index a temporary matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

When I want to access a specific element of a matrix, I use indexing with parentheses:

```
m = calc_stuff(...);
x = m(index1, index2);
```

However, I often want to do that in one line of code, like this:

```
x = calc_stuff(...)(index1, index2);
```

How can I express it?

A specific example:

```
m = cumsum(rand(10,4));
x = m(10, 1);
```

The above script calculates some sums of random variables, and then I take one example value out of the result matrix.

How could I write it as one line? The following doesn't work:

```
x = cumsum(rand(10,4))(10, 1);
```

> Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

Here, I want a general syntax, which is applicable for any calculation, not necessarily involving random variables.

Comment: Octave allows to do this, but in Matlab you need to use `subsref`. Check @Sardar_Usama link for a complete explanation

Comment: If you just want to put it on one line, separate the two lines with a semicolon and put them on one line. E.g. `m = calc_stuff(...); x = m(index1, index2);`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the "Functional Programming Constructs" on the [FileExchange](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39735-functional-programming-constructs)).

Especially the file paren.m does what you need. So you would write

```
x = paren( cumsum(rand(10,4)), 10, 1 );
```

Perhaps not as elegant as the direct "()"notation, but that is not supported in MATLAB in the way you would like to use it.